# CodenameOne button disabled when opening Cordova hybrid app

Tags: cordova, codenameone

I have downloaded the CodenameOne CN1Cordova Tools and have run

```
ant create -Did=com.example.hello -Dname=HelloWorld
```

from the command line and have got a "build successful" message. However when I try to open this created project in IntelliJ 2017.3.2, the CodenameOne button and menu are not enabled? You can try to run it and the Simulator appears only to show an error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific tool generates a NetBeans project not an IntelliJ project so that won't work.

You can create a new Codename One project in IntelliJ and then copy the generated files on top of the existing files to see how that works.